# Properly handling gRPC types to SQL ORM

Tags: go

I'm implementing a gRPC server and using an ORM called Boiler for Go. I've gotten to a point where I've built all my models and protos and now I'm handling specific type issues.

Within my protobuf files I've declared most types as `strings`. However my ORM treats (due to how it interfaces with Postgres) strings as null.String in it's models. Hence when I attempt something like so I get an error:

```
user := &models.User{
    FirstName:   req.FirstName,
    LastName:    req.LastName,
    Email:       req.Email,
    Gender:      req.Gender,
    PhoneNumber: req.PhoneNumber,
}
```

The error: `services/users.go:46:3: cannot use req.FirstName (type string) as type null.String in field value`

The question is what would be the most appropriate way of handling this situation. I could: generate a new struct (which I'm already using for data validation) and cast them into null.String or I suppose I could attempt to force the casting somehow?

The question then becomes if a user doesn't supply a value in the API and the validation process allows it, how would that handle the non-existing record?

Edit: Seems like SQLBoiler developers have a package for handling nulls separately. ie. `null.StringFrom()`, `null.Int15From` etc. which I'd in essence wrap all my fields with as such:

```
user := &models.User{
    FirstName:        null.StringFrom(req.FirstName),
    LastName:         null.StringFrom(req.LastName),
    Email:            null.StringFrom(req.Email),
    Password:         string(password_hash),
    Role:             "BASIC_USER",
    Status:           "ACTIVE",
    Gender:           null.Int16From(req.Gender),
    PhoneNumber:      null.StringFrom(req.PhoneNumber),
    VerificationCode: null.StringFrom(code.String()),
}
```

Feels kind of dirty but I don't see any other options. Suggestions/opinions anyone?